# C# Nullable Types and the Value property

Tags: c#

I'm a little unclear on when/if the `Value` property on nullable types must be used when getting the value contained in a nullable type. Consider the following example:

```
int? x = 10;

Console.WriteLine("The value of 'x' is " + x.Value);
Console.WriteLine("The value of 'x' is " + x);
```

Both of these return the same value (10).

However, if I initially set `x` to `null`, the first `Console.WriteLine` throws an exception and the second one does not.

So, my question is this. What is the point of using the `Value` property? It doesn't appear to be needed to get the actual value (even if it's `null`) and will throw an exception if the value is indeed `null`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It *is* needed usually - just not in your particular case. The type of `x` is `Nullable<int>`, not `int` - and there's no *implicit* conversion from `Nullable<T>` to `T`.

Let's look at what's happening in your example though. Your final line is being converted into:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("The value of 'x' is ", x));
```

That's boxing `x`, which will result in *either* a boxed `int` *or* a null reference... both of which are handled by `string.Concat`.

When you're *not* converting to a string via string concatenation, e.g. if you wanted:

```
int nonNullable = x.Value;
```

then you *do* have to use the `Value` property - or an explicit cast, or possibly a null coalescing operator, or a call to `GetValueOrDefault`:

```
int nonNullable = (int) x;
int alternative = x ?? 20;
int andAnother = x.GetValueOrDefault(20);
```

Comment: Or possibly x.GetValueOrDefault(20), however null coalescing is obviously nice, didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @jishi: Good option, I'll add it in there.

Answer (score 10):

`x` and `x.Value` have different types.

```
    static void Meth(int i)
    {
        int? x = 5;
        Meth(x);
        Meth(x.Value);
    }
```

Second line doesn't compile.

So reason of using `x.Value` is obvious - you need to call it when you need the actual value. And `NullReferenceException` is reasonable, because `null` doen't correspond to value of value type.

Comment: But you can have `Meth((int)x);` and it will compile. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard `(int)x` is same as `x.Value`

Answer (score 2):

You should access Value property if HasValue property returns true, otherwise you will get an exception.
Your example works because Nullable has overloaded ToString() method and C# compiler supports shortcuts for this type.

Answer (score 2):

when `x` is null `x.Value` will throw a System.InvalidOperationException exception (no matter what is the type of x)

`string + null = string` : no exception

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .value for a nullable int. you can check the value like this

```
int? x = null;
int valXX = x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0;
Console.WriteLine("The value of 'x' is ->" + x + "<-");
Console.WriteLine("The value of 'valXX' is ->" + valXX + "<-");
```