# Why is 'null integer' not throwing 'NullReferenceException' after string conversion?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

In the below code, I am getting null reference exception and it's fine since string is null -

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  static string  r = null;
  public static void Main()
  {
    string s = "";

    try
    {
        s = r.ToString(); 
        Console.Write("Successful");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception via using null int...." + ex);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
exception via using null int....System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

But when I use this code, why am I not getting null reference exception?
Does nullable integer variable not has null value ?

```
using System;
public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string s = "";
    int? i = null;

    try
    {
        s = i.ToString(); 
        Console.Write("Successful");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception via using null int...." + ex);
    }


    Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Successful
```

Comment: does s contain the actual value when you print it if you do assign a value to it?

Comment: which version  of c# are you using ?

Comment: i is an instance of Nullable<Int32>. If you try to use i.Value then you will get the exception you're expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Nullable Types and the Value property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405865/c-sharp-nullable-types-and-the-value-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Nullable<T> HasValue property not throw NullReferenceException on Nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194617/why-does-nullablet-hasvalue-property-not-throw-nullreferenceexception-on-nulls)

Comment: @Jay C# verison 4.6.2

Comment: @H.J.Meijer it prints nothing

Comment: @IanGilroy Yes, you are correct but why it's not throwing exception after converting it to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does s contain the actual value when you print it if you do assign a value to it? the int?'s value should be accessed via

```
.Value
```

so

```
int?.ToString()
```

should print a its type, not its value, so null is fine here, see also: [C# Nullable Types and the Value property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405865/c-sharp-nullable-types-and-the-value-property?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 6):

`int?` is a value type, not a reference type.  `NullReferenceException` is only thrown for reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Because S is an object in memory and it containt a string with zero carathers, but r is only a call to computer to hold a place but you didn t say if it's string so toString isn t possible

when declaring S with a value the compiler make sure as is an object of string and it get's all the string methodes from the object String.

Comment: The question is not about the string r - OP understands that, it is about why the nullable int i does not give a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `T?` notation is a short hand for `System.Nullable<T>`. This type is a struct, not a reference type, and it cannot be `null`. It has a constructor that accepts a `null` reference, and what it does is creates the struct that contains `null` inside it.

Comment: This is what I thought, however if you do i.GetType(), you DO get a null reference exception. What's going on there?